# SSH projects' urls depends on the username

Tags: git, ssh, git-submodules, gerrit

I'm using **gerrit**.

All **project's url** are looking like this :

```
ssh://username@domain:port/project
```

In **standard git server** (gitlab, github...) it look like this :

```
git@domain:project.git
```

My problem is that gerrit url are depending on the **username**.

I want to use submodule in one of my projects, the problem is that in .gitmodules I end up with thing like that :

```
[submodule "MyModule"]
    path = MyModule
    url = ssh://username@domain:port/project
```

This is obviously wrong because the username will be **different for each user**

For the moments here is the options I see to solve this :

**1)** use general ssh adress in gerrit like in other git server (if this is possible)

**2)** use the http adress in .gitmodules and each user will have to adapt his submodules' origin remotes (a script will probably do for that)

**3)** don't deploy .gitsubmodules and use a script that will add the submodules for each users

My questions are :

Is 1) possible ? Is there any other options ? What is the best options ?

Comment: I haven't used here it but want to be helpful. I found this and thought it may be useful to you: https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/user-submodules.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to put the username in the ssh url.  If the username on the server matches the username on Gerrit, the command will work correctly without a username present.  Otherwise, you can use the .ssh/config file to specify the username for a particular server:

```
Host dev.mydomain.com
    User myUserName
```

Now ssh will add the `myUserName@` whenever it sees an ssh call to `dev.mydomain.com`

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. In fact I created a script to help users autoconfigure their ssh config file. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved by using GIT_SSH. The GIT_SSH environment variable defines the path to a script that is used whenever Git needs to create an ssh connection.

You can set it to `GIT_SSH=<PATH>/git-ssh.sh`.
The content of git-ssh.sh will be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh domain:port/project -l $USER
```